# compare two xml fields using Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have checked all questions related to my question none of them has been able to solve my issue. My problem is I need to compare two XML nodes value using XPath. below is the XML

```
<ExtenProp>
 <GenericField>
  <FieldKey>IsDiscount</FieldKey> 
  <FieldValue>True</FieldValue> 
  <Namespace /> 
  <ExtendedProperties /> 
</GenericField>
```

I need to check if IsDiscount is available then value is true or not.
I tried to check like this

```
//do:OrderForms/do:OrderForm/do:ExtendedProperties/do:GenericField[FieldKey="IsDiscount" and FieldValue="True"]
```

and checked if this is equal to true, but this is not working. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: In the XML its `ExtenProp/GenericField` in your XPath its `ExtendedProperties/GenericField`‽

Comment: Can you show a complete example with an XPath that actually fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the right track with that XPath expression. I suspect the problem is merely missing prefixes -which I suppose mapped to default namespace URI- on `FieldKey` and `FieldValue` :

```
...../do:GenericField[do:FieldKey="IsDiscount" and do:FieldValue="True"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the actual text content from that subelements:

```
…/do:GenericField[do:FieldKey/text()="IsDiscount" and do:FieldValue/text()="True"]
```

or

```
…/do:GenericField[string(do:FieldKey)="IsDiscount" and string(do:FieldValue)="True"]
```

Comment: If the text node is the only content of the element, none of the above is necessary, comparing the element with the literal string directly should yield the same result. CMIIW